# Unescape form input to allow some HTML

Tags: html, forms, escaping

I am using the neat [Jazzy Forms plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jazzy-forms/) to build a basic form, but hoping this question is general enough to post here...

I would like to use some HTML in the form input titles, such as `<span>` or `<br>`, but when I do the code is displayed on the front end.

Is there a way to enter HTML so that it outputs the actual HTML? Or will the answer be specific to this plugin? Here is the [form in progress](http://carolineelisa.com/indigo/2012/test-form/), you can see the span tag on the first radio button.

Thanks!

Comment: with php you can use strip_tags http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php it allows you to specify allowed tags

Comment: you might want to ask this on the WordPress Stack. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks dnagirl, will do. If you don't mind explaining... is there a way to migrate the question, or do I ask it again?

Comment: I flagged it so hopefully someone will swoosh it over. If you flag it with a request to move, that may help.